# DBGRID não exibe resultado

Tags: sql-server, delphi

Tenho uma tabela que possui dados cadastrados no `SQLServer`, porém na aplicação os mesmos não aparecem no `dbgrid`.

```pascal
DATASOURCdo dbgrid -> UDM.DSPecas_ordem_servico
```

Ao abrir o form:

```
procedure TFMHome.lbl_BuscosClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UDM.ADODSPecas_ordem_servico.Open;
  FMAltOs.showmodal;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem erro, a não ser que seja as ligações.
Confere se esta tudo certo:

```
DataSource ---ligado---> ADODSPecas_ordem_servico
DbGrid   -----ligado---> DataSource
```

Sendo *ADODSPecas_ordem_servico* um *DataSet* válido (aquele ali que você esta dando Open). E o *DataSource* tem que estar ligado a este *DataSet*.

Faça um confere também no Trio de Conexão:

```
Conexão>>DataSet>>DataSource (se possuir DataSet+Provider também conferir).
```

Comment: nada, o engraçado que quando faço uma nova inserção ele funciona e aparece no dbgrid, ao fechar não está mais lá

Comment: Qual componente esta usando como Grid ?